# Can order come from chaos?

Tags: theology, determinism, materialism, cosmology

I've been considering the idea that matter, or some material substance, has either always existed, or just began to exist because it's necessary that it exist. In either event, it was chaotic, constantly moving and without any discernible form. After so much *time*, from this chaotic matter came an intelligent entity (God) that was able to move within the frame of time. After even more *time*, God learned everything there was about matter, enabling God to bring the chaotic matter to order.

Is there anything illogical about this idea?

Can a single act of order come from chaos?

Comment: Please define matter. Everybody forgets to do this. You say it exists eternally and yet you'll find it difficult to prove it exists right now. Metaphysics is not straightforward. You assume that an intelligent God arose from matter and there is certainly something illogical about this idea, just as there is about the eternal existence of matter. Likewise, a thing cannot move if it has no form. You have also reified space-time, which leads to well-known logical problems. A somewhat muddled question I'd say.

Comment: @PeterJ Does my edit make more sense? Basically, I define matter as the first "stuff". Maybe a bunch of atoms or particles constantly moving. Whether it's eternal or not isn't a big concern of mine. I have no problem with the idea that it just randomly began to exist, so that it's beginning would be the beginning of time. However, this beginning is not the "Big Bang", but rather *a* beginning. And within this beginning, God is prepared.

Comment: `God learned everything there was about matter, enabling God to bring the chaotic matter to order` Chaos cannot be learned. At least, one must make some assumptions about how chaos is functioning, which means one has brought in some order to (thoughts about) it.

Comment: Note that "chaotic" processes such as random data can time to time form samples/configurations of pretty clear patterns.

Comment: What about the other gods? Had they appeared as a result of natural selection, too?

Comment: @ttnphns Do you mean to say that given enough time, what seems to be chaotic can take on a sort of intelligent configuration?

Comment: @Rodrigo There's really no need. Once the first God was prepared, It could then prepare any other gods much quicker than waiting for it to happen by chance.

Comment: `given enough time` How can time accompany complete chaos? Physical or psychological time is usually thought of as a gauge of ordered events one "earlier" than another. If you have another idea of time - please define it.

Comment: @ttnphns I've always thought *time* is simply the measurement of movement. So that as long as something is moving or changing, it can be measured with time.

Comment: But chaos is not a directional movement anyhow (rather is a vortex), how then can it be measured?

Comment: I still feel that the question has too many assumptions. You ask whether the idea is 'illogical' and I'd say yes, since the very idea of existence as you define it is logically problematic. If materialism worked we'd all jump on board. Also, the idea that matter preceeds God is odd. What is God for in this model? Why not just leave Him out, like Democritus?

Comment: @anonymouswho If you think *natural selection* is a synonym for *chance*, I think you should study it again. Anyway, at least the first god should develop by natural selection, if not then how?

Comment: @PeterJ What do you mean with "if materialism worked"? Are you supposing it didn't? Like... China didn't work?

Comment: @Rodrigo Materialism fails under analysis. It does not work. It is endorsed where folks can't think of a better idea but leaves those who endorse it unable to make any sense of metaphysics. If a theory endorses materialism it is not 'illogical',but is, rather, logically absurd. In Butler's 'Erewhon' the Professors of Unreason advise us to abandon the 'absurdity  of the extremes' (ie. say,  materialism and idealism) for the 'illogical mean', and this indicates the important difference between 'illogical' and 'logically absurd'.

Comment: @PeterJ What do you mean with "does not work"? It is incomplete, but every knowledge is incomplete! Appending a "gaseous vertebrate" to the equation adds nothing! What's the *sense* to be made of metaphysics? Metaphysics is not the foundation of knowledge, it's just where we take our hypothesis from. And Confucius also taught the *Doctrine of the Mean*, but he was not a disciple of absurd.

Comment: @Rodrigo Materialism gives rise to logical contradictions and in metaphysics this is the kiss of death. Are you unable to make sense of metaphysics? Would this prove that I cannot do so either? Metaphysics is not the foundation if knowledge, that would be experience, but it is the only way for the intellect to understand the world. Don't believe all those philosophers who tell you metaphysics is nonsensical. There are others who say it makes perfect sense. Confucius was not well informed, as he himself is reported as conceding. Try Lao Tsu, who understood metaphysics. .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64253/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-peterj).

Comment: @Rodrigo Yeah I think I wasn't paying enough attention to your comment. Natural selection is something I would consider to be applicable only after the beginning of our universe, as I believe the universe to be very strictly deterministic. So the appearance of matter and the formation of God are the only "random" things.

Comment: @ttnphns Do you think I should maybe consider a more narrowly defined word than "chaos"? I've read the universe was not subject to it's deterministic nature before the "Big Bang", so that's why I chose chaos. Do you think one of thes words, from the Hebrew [תֹּ֫הוּ](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/8414.htm), would work better?

Answer (score 1):

The Taoist cosmology actually operates in a very similar way.  [Wuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuji_(philosophy)) (無極) is a concept similar enough to the chaos you describe to draw an analogy.  From Wuji, comes a single point, Taiji (太極), which is often translated as the "supreme ultimate," with yin and yang.  Taiji then expands outwards to encompass the whole of the reality we live in.  The point where Wiji becomes Taiji is a subject of great fascination, for it is a moment where a thing is polar yet non-polar.  It has all the differentiation needed to flourish, yet is yet undifferentiated.

I would leave it to a Taoist or a scholar to pen the exact connection between their cosmology and yours, but I see enough of a similarity to say it's worth looking into further.

Answer (score -1):

The distinction between order and chaos is an illusion. Whatever appears chaotic from one perspective appears ordered from another. "Chaos" & "order" become meaningless and arbitrary concepts when you look at them at a deeper level.

I believe this is expressed best in the following excerpt from the [Principia Discordia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Discordia) :

> The Aneristic Principle is that of apparent order; the Eristic
>   Principle is that of apparent disorder. Both order and disorder are
>   man made concepts and are artificial divisions of pure chaos, which is
>   a level deeper than is the level of distinction making.
>
> With our
>   concept-making apparatus called "the brain" we look at reality through
>   the ideas-about-reality which our cultures give us. The
>   ideas-about-reality are mistakenly labeled "reality" and unenlightened
>   people are forever perplexed by the fact that other people, especially
>   other cultures, see "reality" differently.
>
> It is only the
>   ideas-about-reality which differ. Real (capital-T) True reality is a
>   level deeper than is the level of concept. We look at the world
>   through windows on which have been drawn grids (concepts). Different
>   philosophies use different grids. A culture is a group of people with
>   rather similar grids. Through a window we view chaos, and relate it to
>   the points on our grid, and thereby understand it. The order is in the
>   grid. That is the Aneristic Principle.
>
> Western philosophy is
>   traditionally concerned with contrasting one grid with another grid,
>   and amending grids in hopes of finding a perfect one that will account
>   for all reality and will, hence, (say unenlightened westerners) be
>   true. This is illusory; it is what we Erisians call the Aneristic
>   Illusion. Some grids can be more useful than others, some more
>   beautiful than others, some more pleasant than others, etc., but none
>   can be more True than any other.
>
> Disorder is simply unrelated
>   information viewed through some particular grid. But, like "relation",
>   no-relation is a concept. Male, like female, is an idea about sex. To
>   say that male-ness is "absence of female-ness", or vice versa, is a
>   matter of definition and metaphysically arbitrary. The artificial
>   concept of no-relation is the Eristic Principle.
>
> The belief that
>   "order is true" and disorder is false or somehow wrong, is the
>   Aneristic Illusion. To say the same of disorder, is the Eristic
>   Illusion.
>
> The point is that (little-t) truth is a matter of definition
>   relative to the grid one is using at the moment, and that (capital-T)
>   Truth, metaphysical reality, is irrelevant to grids entirely. Pick a
>   grid, and through it some chaos appears ordered and some appears
>   disordered. Pick another grid, and the same chaos will appear
>   differently ordered and disordered.
>
> — Malaclypse the Younger,
>   Principia Discordia, pages 00049–00050